# Fill remainder of line with spaces to hit fixed width

Tags: python, r, string, bash, text-parsing

I have some plaintext data files that should be fixed width and space delimited.  However, the far right-hand columns are rarely populated and for those rows with missing values the row's text stops at the last populated column.  Since the characters cease the file isn't really fixed width and there aren't any delimiters or missing symbols (NAs).

When I examine the headers I see that the maximal row structure would be

- 17 columns with 16 spaces
- 77 char for data giving fixed width of 93 including delimiters
- Column structure of (4,2,2,2,2,5,5,3,8,5,7,4,4,6,6,6,6)

What I'd like to do is add 93-POPULATED_LENGTH spaces to the end of each line so that I can parse it as fixed width for data analysis.  A solution in Bash or lightweight Python would be ideal.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Please show your attempts at it.

Comment: The Bash to do this is likely shorter than a post telling me to go away.

Comment: I am sorry, I have never meant to send you away. I have explained what SO is not. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). BTW, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, this should do

```
MAXCOLS = 93
with open('words.txt') as in_f, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as out_f:
    for line in in_f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        l = len(line)
        padline = MAXCOLS-l
        out_line = line+' '*padline+'\n'
        out_f.write(out_line)
```

For example, given a smaller fixed width of 21 columns and using an 'X' to mark the spaces

with an input file of

```
ciao come va
oggi meglio di domani
ieri peggio di oggi
my puzzle is big
yours puzzle is small
```

it produces an output file of

```
ciao come vaXXXXXXXXX
oggi meglio di domani
ieri peggio di oggiXX
my puzzle is bigXXXXX
yours puzzle is small
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just turning your file into a csv using the tr utility. It can replace whitespace with commas:

```
echo 'adam jane sam' > names.txt
cat names.txt | tr -s ' ' ','
adam,jane,sam
```

The trailing whitespace will just become a comma with nothing following and both R and pandas will read that as a NA/NaN.

Answer (score 0):

$ awk '{printf("%-93s\n", $0) }' file.txt > file2.txt

This did the job but no idea why.  AWK and SED provide their black magic as usual.